# Confused on Ruby URL parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Questions model that has a number of different fields/parameters.  If I want to view all of them, I just go to:

```
http://localhost:3002/questions
```

In order to view one specific question, I go to something like

```
http://localhost:3002/questions/1
```

How can I view the questions that satisfy a specific parameter requirement?  Something like

```
http://localhost:3002/questions?difficulty=1
```

just gives the same result as viewing all questions.  I know that syntactically I'm way off... but can anyone lead me in the right direction?  How can I set this up on the controller-side?

Comment: You may want to be specific about your web app framework. It sounds like you are talking about Rails.


In a URI, everything after the ? becomes parameters that are sent as part of the GET request.

Comment: Does `?difficulty=1/1/` mean `difficulty`should be `true` or something like `difficulty` should equal the string `'1/1/'`?

Comment: @spickermann I edited that /1/ out, sorry.

Comment: Rails isn't magic. The parameters are parsed out by the router and passed to the controller in a params hash. Given your URL, you will find that params[:difficulty] == 1 in your controller and view. Use this value to refine your query, eg. Questions.where(difficulty: params[:difficulty])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to intercept the param in your controller and filter your results using the param.

```
def index
  if params[:difficulty]
    @questions = Question.where(difficulty: params[:difficulty])
  else
    @questions = Question.all
  end
end
```

Comment: This worked perfectly... I know understand how these URLs/controllers work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameter depends on your condition

see the example

**View:**

```
<%= link_to "View", questions_path(:difficulty => 1) %>
```

**note:** you can send dynamic values to **difficulty** parameter

**Controller:**

```
def index
  if params[:difficulty]
    @questions = Question.all.where(:difficulty => params[:difficulty])
  else
    @questions = Question.all
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :questions
```

Answer (score -1):

You should provide a little more information, but maybe this will point you in the right direction if you are running a rails framework.  I would create associations within the database objects so they can share certain characteristics. Check this out and see if this is what you're trying to do, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html .  As for as the controller, that is where you'll define the method for calling the associations.